# Python, Writing Multiple Lines

Tags: python

Sorry if this question comes across a little newbie but iv'e been looking for a while and cannot find anything on this.

I am testing how to Write Multiple Lines to a txt file on a new line per request. I can't seem to get it to write to a newline. This is what I have currently.

```
import __builtin__

title=('1.0')
des=('1.1')
img=('1.2')
tag=('1.3')
tag2=('1.4')
tag3=('1.5')

tf = 'textfile.txt'
f2 = open(tf, 'a+')
f2.writelines([title,des,img,tag,tag2,tag3])
f2.close()

title=('2.0')
des=('2.1')
img=('2.2')
tag=('2.3')
tag2=('2.4')
tag3=('2.5')

tf = 'textfile.txt'
f2 = open(tf, 'a+')
f2.writelines([title,des,img,tag,tag2,tag3])
f2.close()

title=('3.0')
des=('3.1')
img=('3.2')
tag=('3.3')
tag2=('3.4')
tag3=('3.5')

tf = 'textfile.txt'
f2 = open(tf, 'a+')
f2.writelines([title,des,img,tag,tag2,tag3])
f2.close()
```

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('xyz.txt', 'w') as fp:
    fp.writelines([ each_line + '\n' for each_line in ['line_1','line_2','line_3']])
```

[`writelines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?#file.writelines) does not append a newline `'\n'` while writing.

```
writelines(...)
writelines(sequence_of_strings) -> None.  Write the strings to the file.
```

Note that newlines are not added.  The sequence can be any iterable object
 producing strings. This is equivalent to calling [`write()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?#file.write) for each string.

```
line_1
line_2
line_3
```

So you might have to do something like this:

Case 1:

```
tf = 'textfile.txt'
f2 = open(tf, 'a+')
f2.writelines([str(data) + '\n' for data in [title,des,img,tag,tag2,tag3]])
f2.close()
```

Case 2:

```
tf = 'textfile.txt'
f2 = open(tf, 'a+')
f2.write(', '.join([str(data) for data in [title,des,img,tag,tag2,tag3]]) + '\n')
f2.close()
```

Comment: Tanveer Alam that's awesome thanks for that! I was hoping to have the result like this: title,des,img,tag,tag2,tag3 (new line here) title,des,img,tag,tag2,tag3 (new line here) so the first set are all on one line separated by commas then a new line is added for the next save. Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: @BubblewrapBeast See case2 in the answer.I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `\n` after every line. For example:

```
f2.write(title + '\n')
f2.write(des + '\n')
f2.write(tag + '\n')
...
```